# Adding a jquery datepicker to react component

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, datepicker

I am trying to integrate a datepicker to a react component. I am using [pickaday](https://github.com/dbushell/Pikaday) jquery library for the datepicker. To implement this I created the following component.

**DatePicker.js.jsx**

```
var DatePicker = React.createClass({
//This is a callback to parent component for updating the state
    changeDuration: function (date) {
        this.props.changeDuration(this.props.id, date);
    },

    componentDidMount: function () {
        _self = this;
        new Pikaday({
            field: document.getElementById(this.props.id),
            format: 'D MMM YYYY',
            onSelect: function () {
                _self.changeDuration(this.getMoment())
            },
            minDate: this.props.minDate
        });
    },


    render: function () {
        return (
            <input type="text" name={this.props.name} id={this.props.id} defaultValue={this.props.value}/>
        )
    }
});
```

The issue here is that on first page load I can choose the datepicker and it works as expected, but if I change it again without reloading it wont work and shows below error in console.

> Uncaught TypeError: _self.changeDuration is not a function

Could someone tell me what am doing wrong here?

Comment: _self = this; should be var  _self = this;

Comment: @ved exactly..cant believe this was the issue. I was fiddling with this since yesterday.Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake is your variable is without type declaration.

```
_self = this;
```

should be

```
var _self = this
```